# sending empty string to list items if null

Tags: java

```
for (int lstSize = 0; lstSize < obj.size(); lstSize++) {
    if (obj.get(lstSize).getCuffSize() == null) {
        obj.get(lstSize).setCuffSize("");
    }
}
```

I have an ArrayList, where there are many items which has a value of null, can i set values as empty string, if my items in my List Object holds null value.

For instance:

While looping i am getting `cuffSize` as `null`, so i am setting it to `empty String`. But there are such many items in my Object which needs to be set like this. **Is there any better way where can i set all the items in my object holding null value to empty string?**

Comment: Why can't you leave the list members as simply null until you actually need to check the content of the list for its intended purpose?

Comment: Enhanced for would get rid of all the `get()` calls.

Comment: The answer is basically "Yes, if have access to wherever your list is being initialized." You could easily do your `null` checks whenever you're first making the list. But barring that, you're going to have to loop over the list and replace those values one way or another (Keppil's comment suggests a cleaner way to do that). You're probably not gaining very much either way unless your list really is so long that a O(n) operation is actually a problem (and then I'd expect this particular issue to be the least of your worries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enhanced for would get rid of all the `get()` calls:

```
for (MyObj elem : obj) {
    if (elem.getCuffSize() == null) {
        elem.setCuffSize("");
    }
}
```

In Java 8 you will be able to do this in a cleaner way using Lambdas, but in Java 7 I don't know of a better way than looping.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than setting many properties from null to empty string later I think its better to initialize those properties inside your class itself to empty String like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String cuffSize = ""; // init to empty String here
    private String somethingElse = ""; // init to empty String here
    ...
}
```

Then even if you don't call setters of cuffSize it will contain an empty String instead of null.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you add a method in the class of your object. which do the `null->""` logic.

The method could return the object reference, so that you could do it during adding it into your list. something like:

```
public Obj null2empty(){
  field1=field1==null?"":field1;
  field2=field2==null?"":field2;
  field3=field3==null?"":field3;
....
  return this;

}

list.add(obj.null2empty());
```

also possible to do it in iteration:

```
for(Obj obj : list) obj.null2empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29):

```
Iterator<MyObject> it = obj.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{ 
    MyObject obj = it.next();
    if(obj == null) { .. } 
}
```

Comment: @downvoter I don't see a reason for a downvote. You're downvoting my answers all the time. I reported this too.

Answer (score -1):

The implementation of getCuffSize() method can be below, so that your end objective is met

```
public String getCuffSize()
{
   return (cuffSize == null) ? "" : cuffSize;
}
```